# Condição no MySql para valor especifico de unidade de medida

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma view no BD onde preciso trazer um quantidade total de KG/LT de produtos esperados para recebimento na empresa, preciso incluir uma condição que quando a unidade for TON ou TN ele multiplique por 1000, pois quando é tonelada, ele calcula como se fosse unitário normal, essas informações são retiradas de XML, é possível?

Segue a consulta atual:

```
SELECT SUM(i_prod_quant) as QUANT, pha_table.pha_emp as EMP FROM pha_table 
            INNER JOIN phs_table ON pha_table.pha_parceiro_cnpj = phs_table.phs_parceiro_cnpj 
            INNER JOIN nfe_table ON nfe_table.nfe_chave = phs_table.phs_nfe_chave 
            INNER JOIN i_nfe_table ON i_nfe_table.i_nfe_chave = nfe_table.nfe_chave GROUP BY EMP
```

Comment: Ulisses, pelo que entendi o campo "i_prod_quat" possui a informação referente à quantidade do produto, mas haveria um campo que informa qual é a unidade relacionada à quantidade do produto? Se sim, qual seria esse campo? Você pode incluir na sua pergunta um esquema da sua pha_table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso basta fazer uso de uma condição com o `IF` no seu select que dará certo, o `IF` deverá ver a unidade de medida para fazer a multiplicação.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(UNIDADE='TON', i_prod_quant*1000, i_prod_quant)) as QUANT, pha_table.pha_emp as EMP FROM pha_table 
            INNER JOIN phs_table ON pha_table.pha_parceiro_cnpj = phs_table.phs_parceiro_cnpj 
            INNER JOIN nfe_table ON nfe_table.nfe_chave = phs_table.phs_nfe_chave 
            INNER JOIN i_nfe_table ON i_nfe_table.i_nfe_chave = nfe_table.nfe_chave GROUP BY EMP
```

Você tmbém pode ter o mesmo efeito utizando o CASE

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN UNIDADE='TON' THEN i_prod_quant*1000 ELSE i_prod_quant END) as QUANT, pha_table.pha_emp as EMP FROM pha_table 
            INNER JOIN phs_table ON pha_table.pha_parceiro_cnpj = phs_table.phs_parceiro_cnpj 
            INNER JOIN nfe_table ON nfe_table.nfe_chave = phs_table.phs_nfe_chave 
            INNER JOIN i_nfe_table ON i_nfe_table.i_nfe_chave = nfe_table.nfe_chave GROUP BY EMP
```

Comment: E se eu precisar com mais de uma opção, tentei colocar mas está dando erro!

Comment: Consegui! obrigado pela resposta!